# compact jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a site I use jQuery. To keep this code short and simple I would like to compress some code a litte. In my jQuery-code I use the following code:

```
$(".dienst1").hover(function() {
    $( ".toelichting1" ).stop().fadeIn(500);
        $( ".uitleg1" ).stop().fadeTo( "fast", 0.9 );
        $( ".uitleg2" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $( ".uitleg3" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $( ".uitleg4" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $( ".uitleg5" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $( ".uitleg6" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $(".readmore1").stop().show();
        }, function() {
    $( ".toelichting1" ).stop().fadeOut(10);
        $( ".uitleg2" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $( ".uitleg3" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $( ".uitleg4" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $( ".uitleg5" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $( ".uitleg6" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $(".readmore1").stop().hide();
});

$(".dienst2").hover(function() {
    $( ".toelichting2" ).stop().fadeIn(500);
        $( ".uitleg1" ).stop().fadeTo( "fast", 0.9 );
        $( ".uitleg2" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $( ".uitleg3" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $( ".uitleg4" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $( ".uitleg5" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $( ".uitleg6" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
        $(".readmore1").stop().show();
        }, function() {
    $( ".toelichting2" ).stop().fadeOut(10);
        $( ".uitleg2" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $( ".uitleg3" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $( ".uitleg4" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $( ".uitleg5" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $( ".uitleg6" ).stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
        $(".readmore1").stop().hide();
});
```

I use this code multiple times. Is it possible to make a function of this or is there another way to keep away from repeating code like this?

Comment: While not the best fit of a question for SO, I'll offer you the advice that you should show your markup and describe the intent of the code in order to get the best advice. It's hard to know exactly what could be trimmed down here without knowing what it's supposed to do, and what it's operating on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute starts with selector `[name^="value"]`

In your code you can try:

```
$("div[class^='.dienst']").hover(function() {
    $("div[class^='.toelichting']").stop().fadeIn(500);
        $("div[class^='.uitleg']").stop().fadeTo( "fast", 0.9 );
        $(".readmore1").stop().show();
});
```

Just change `div` for the `html` tag that's associated with the class.

I realised that you have different time values when fading, i think that for the last nested childs you will need a different way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making the same action against several different classes, you can group the elements like this: `$(".uitleg1, .uitleg2")`.

Then you can group them all together and make a single call to `stop` and `fadeTo`, like this:

```
$(".dienst1").hover(function() {
    $( ".uitleg1" ).stop()
                   .fadeTo( "fast", 0.9 );

    $( ".uitleg2,.uitleg3,.uitleg4,.uitleg5,.uitleg6" ).stop()
                                                       .fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
    $(".readmore1").stop()
                   .show();
}, function() {
    $( ".toelichting1" ).stop()
                        .fadeOut(10);

    $( ".uitleg2,.uitleg3,.uitleg4,.uitleg5,.uitleg6" ).stop()
                                                       .fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );

    $(".readmore1").stop().hide();
});
```

To conserve memory, you can create a "listener" function for the hover events then attach them to the jQuery event, like this:

```
function dienst1HoverListener() {
    $( ".toelichting1" ).stop().fadeIn(500);
    $( ".uitleg1" ).stop()
                   .fadeTo( "fast", 0.9 );

    $( ".uitleg2,.uitleg3,.uitleg4,.uitleg5,.uitleg6" ).stop()
                                                       .fadeTo( "slow", 0.2 );
    $(".readmore1").stop()
                   .show();
}

function dienst1HoverCompleteListener() {
    $( ".toelichting1" ).stop()
                        .fadeOut(10);

    $( ".uitleg2,.uitleg3,.uitleg4,.uitleg5,.uitleg6" ).stop()
                                                       .fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );

    $(".readmore1").stop()
                   .hide();
}

$(".dienst1").hover(dienst1HoverListener, dienst1HoverCompleteListener);
```